# Prevent blocking after using matplotlib.fig.canvas timer for animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script that uses matplotlib within a `multiprocessing.Process` to draw images.

I would like to extend the software to plot motions using `fig.canvas.new_timer` while keeping the matplotlib figure open at any time.
However I run into a blocking issue when I combine animations and plots.

I cannot change the use of multiprocessing at this point as the original software is designed that way.

The following example demonstrates the issue as it blocks on the `create_animation`. It should show a gray gradient followed by a small random animation. The next gray gradient after the animation is never executed.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

ts = 0
timer = None
def callback(line): 
    global ts
    global timer
    x = np.random.randint(0, 1024)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 1024)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    plt.pause(0.01)
    print(ts)
    ts += 1
    if ts == 50:
        print('stop callback')
        timer.stop()
        plt.show(block=False)


def create_animation(fig, ax, line):
    global ts
    global timer
    r,g,b = 0,0,0
    ax.set_facecolor((r,g,b))

    ts = 0
    interval = 10
    timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=interval,
                                 callbacks=[(callback, [line], {})])
    timer.start()
    #plt.ioff()
    plt.show(block=True)




def run():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot([], [], color='grey', marker='o')
    minx, maxx, miny, maxy = 0, 1024, 0, 1024
    ax.axis([minx, maxx, miny, maxy])


    # plot gray gradient
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1024)
    data = np.tile(x, (1024, 1))
    ax.imshow(data, cmap='gray', aspect='auto')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    time.sleep(2)

    # this blocks
    create_animation(fig, ax, line)
    plt.ion()

    # plot gray gradient
    time.sleep(3)
    x = np.linspace(1, 0, 1024)
    data = np.tile(x, (1024, 1))
    ax.imshow(data, cmap='gray', aspect='auto')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target = run, args=())
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    while True:
        pass
```

Comment: Uhhh this looks a lot like it's going to fail at some point. However, in order to help you here it would make sense to tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve with this code. Why are you using multiprocessing in the first place? How is the desired output to look like? What are the different parts in the code supposed to do?

Comment: The example should show a gray gradient for 2 seconds, followed by a plot that randomly draws a point, then again a gray gradient. It will however block on the second plot. The reason the example uses multiprocessing is that the original software I work on is designed that way. I can't change this at this point.

Comment: And why do you need multiprocessing for that?

Comment: The original software is designed that way and I cannot change it at this point.

Comment: Ok, so which part is "the original software" here? Again, explain your code. Please do so *inside* the question, not in the comments - they are just meant to tell you at which points your question needs to improve.

Comment: This is just an example that demonstrates the blocking issue. I will comment the example code.